# WebAPI Register passing already existing email, what's the expected return HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm a scenario where somebody tries to register a new account but the email already exists, what should be the HttpStatusCode returned to the client:

**HttpStatusCode.OK** ?

Is there somewhere online a list of possible scenarios with matching HttpStatusCode?

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent list? 409 Conflict may fit your use case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Are you looking for our opinion as to what we THINK it should be?  Or if there's a standard?

Comment: @MikeMarks to be honest, I think I would rather go with the standard since the API will be consumed by various 3rd party clients

Comment: @StevenV From Wikipedia, it seems this should be a 200 OK, right?

Comment: @Developer A lot of APIs do that. And they send a standard error format that any implementing application should check for and understand.

Comment: Depend on your client/consumer, How does he implement the HttpResponseMessage ? In my Web API i returned back .Forbidden and the Content will be string explaning that the user already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpStatusCode` should be 200 OK, because in the end, the `HttpResponse` is in fact successful regardless whether or not the email exists.  You are dealing with a separate issue.    You shouldn't intermingle the state of an `HttpResponse` (the status code) with something that literally has nothing to do with `Http`.  What if the email doesn't exist?  Well, I would handle that separate than what you're trying to do.  Say something like:

```
if (EmailExists())
    // alert the user or do something to let them know, hey the email
    // has already been registered, try again
else
    // continue with your execution
```